# CGLib Proxy for Integer (Final class) in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, cglib

I need such a usage:

**For each request I want to inject userId into DemoController** But because of being a final class without empty constructor I can not inject it. What is the best practice in such cases? A service with request scope is fine?

```
@Configuration
public class CityFactory{

   @Bean(name = {"currentUserId")
   @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST,proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
   @Autowired
   public Integer getUserId(HttpServletRequest request) {
       return UserUtil.getCurrentUserId(request.getServerName());
   }
}


@RequestMapping("/demo")
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    Ingeter userId;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(@PathVariable("name") String name, Model model) {
        Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.addAttribute("user", userId);
        return new ModelAndView("v3/test", "m", model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to subclass Integer?

Comment: @Sean: Because that's how CGLIB works

Comment: @skaffman I can understand subclassing the controller or the id classs, but why Integer?

Comment: @Sean: Because the Spring bean is an Integer, and scoped proxies work by subclassing.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to create an explicit class called `UserId`, which in turn contains an integer. Not only will this play nicer with CGLIB's proxying, it also clarifies your design.

Comment: For such suggestion, I prefer AtomicInteger class which is provided at concurrency package already. Thanks. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Supplier or Provider

```
@Configuration
public class CityFactory{

   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public Supplier<Integer> getUserId(HttpServletRequest request) {
       return () -> UserUtil.getCurrentUserId(request.getServerName());
   }
}
@RequestMapping("/demo")
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    Supplier<Ingeter> getUserId;
```